# How to substitute values in mathematics equations in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sympy

I am getting data in form of dictionary from data base as:

```
in_dict = {"x":2,"y":"x+2","z":"y+2"}
```

and I am getting my maths equation in form of string as :

```
eqn = "(x+2)*y/z"
```

What is the easiest method to substitute values in equation and to give final solution?

Note: One should be aware that values in dictionary come randomly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Comment: What would the answer to this be? You havn't posted an expected output?

Comment: People rely on the example structure that `x` is a constant and `y` and `z` are interpreted as expressions of `x`. Is this always the case?

Comment: No, the equation can have any number of variables and and different variables are dependent on different variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of the previous `sympy` answer, here is an approach which is dynamic with respect to the size and content of the `in_dict` variables. The biggest step is to map the sympy symbols (python vars of `x, y, z`) to their symbolic representations that get passed through your `in_dict`

```
import sympy

def eval_eqn(eqn,in_dict):
    subs = {sympy.symbols(key):item for key,item in in_dict.items()}
    ans = sympy.simplify(eqn).evalf(subs = subs)

    return ans
```

The original inputs:

```
in_dict = {"x":2,"y":"x+2","z":"y+2"}
eqn = "(x+2)*y/z"
print(eval_eqn(eqn,in_dict))
```

`2.66666666666667`

A different set of inputs:

```
in_dict = {"a":2, "b": 4, "c":"a+2*b","d":"4*b + c"}
eqn = "c**2 + d**2"
print(eval_eqn(eqn,in_dict))
```

`776.000000000000`

Comment: what if the dict values have data frame column values. say I have a column df[bikes] it has multiple values. when we assign to the dict 'a', will the function work?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have only three variables,

```
x = d["x"]
y = eval(d["y"]) # as it is a string
z = eval(d["z"]) # as it is a string
```

You can use eval:

```
x = eval("(x+2)*y/z")
```

[EDIT 2]
You can use itemgetter for unpacking:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> stuff = {'a': '1', 'b': 'a+1', 'c': '3', 'd': '4'}
>>> a, b, c = list(map(eval, itemgetter('a', 'b', 'c')(stuff))) # for automatic evaluation, but all must be string
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: eval takes care and evaluates the result for y and z in terms of x

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to solve these equations. Install it if you don't already have it using `pip install sympy`

```
import sympy

in_dict = {"x":2,"y":"x+2","z":"y+2"}
x, y, z = sympy.symbols('x y z')
sympy.sympify("(x+2)*y/z").evalf(subs={x:in_dict['x'], y:in_dict['y'], z:in_dict['z']})
```

This will give you output as: `2.66666666666667`

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
from __future__ import division
foo = {"x":2,"y":"x+2","z":"y+2"}
x = "(x+2)*y/z"
x = ("(x+2)*y/z"
     .replace('z', '({})'.format(foo['z']))
     .replace('y', '({})'.format(foo['y']))
     .replace('x', '({})'.format(foo['x'])))
print('x = {}'.format(x))
print('x = {}'.format(eval(x)))
```

Sample output:

```
x = ((2)+2)*((2)+2)/(((2)+2)+2)
x = 2.66666666667
```

Comment: This only works if `x` is the only constant variable, right?

Comment: The eval part will work if x is the only constant (per the question). Yes.